# How can I make a Caesar cipher ignore white spaces and punctuation while keeping the cases?

Tags: python, encryption

This is what I have so far for the cipher code I keep on having errors when I try to type a word that has spaces in it, since it is not a character, my code can't process the spaces and how should I attack this problem?!

```py
message = open("file_test").read()
print(message)

key = str(input("Enter any key\n"))
code = " "
for ch in message:
    ord_value = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ord_value + key
    if cipherValue > ord('z'):
      cipherValue -= 26
    code += chr(cipherValue)

print(code)

new_file = open("encrypted", "w")
new_file.write(code)
```

Comment: additionally, it should be `key = int(input("Enter any key\n"))`, you cannot add a string to an int

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if/else statement.

```
for ch in message:
    if ch.isalpha(): #If the character is a letter
        ord_value = ord(ch)
        cipherValue = ord_value + key
        ...
    else:
        code += chr #If the character is not a letter, just append it to the string.
```

`isalpha` is a string method that returns True if the string contains only letters.